# How to create a sales report for a particular time period in Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am trying to create a sales report to show the number of sales for a particular time period.

**How should I proceed?**

**So far**, I am able to create the form view(*My_Sales_Report*) and linked it to either *sale.order* or *sale.report*. I have created '*My_Sales_Report*' as a base view.I have created two custom fields 'x_data_to' & 'x_data_from' in both the data models ie in sale.order & sale.report.

I think, I don't know where to proceed from here.

Comment: Do you resolve issue? I also try search similar example.